# Impact of small objects of multiple sizes on the performance of Tensorflow object detection API

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I have asked the same question in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72671130/2049763). However, no one has answered the question yet.

I am using Mask R-CNN with Inception ResNet-v2 from [TensorFlow Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection). However, the average precision (AP) and recall (AR) of objects of small size are not good enough.

```
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.172
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.308
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.75      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.174
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = 0.021
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100 ] = 0.157
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = 0.293

 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=  1 ] = 0.148
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets= 10 ] = 0.212
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.213
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = 0.036
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100 ] = 0.205
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = 0.329
```

I am inspecting for the problems and increasing performance by solving those. I found that there are small objects of size less than 32 * 32. And large objects of size more than 512 * 512 of the same class focused in the image. I am considering the impact of multiple shapes from the same object class in object detection.

Is it impacting the training? How can I test the hypothesis? Can someone point me to any similar problem and solution?